# Trying to put some functionalities in a showcase

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to add some functionalities instead of text in a bootstrap 3.0 showcase. It's a long time ago that I learned about programming and I didn't 'program' since the past 10 years. So please don't blame me for questioning.

I have tried to find the solution for the following case but still I can't find the solution here and on Google. I'm trying to add some buttons and text links in a bootstrap showcase function. The links and buttons don't work and I can't find why. I hope somebody can help me.

`

```
<div class="showcase2">
<div class="container">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <header>
                <!--<img src="assets/logo.png" alt="">-->
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <!--Service Blcoks -->
                    <div class="container row servive-block margin-bottom-10">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="servive-block-in servive-block-colored servive-block-blue">
                                <h4>Text</h4>
                                <div><i class="icon-bell"></i></div>
                                <p>Text
                                    <a href="http://www.alinkinshowcase.nl">Link</a>
                                </p>
                                <div class="hero-unit">
                                    <p>Tagline</p>
                                    <p>
                                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
                                            Learn more
                                        </a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="servive-block-in servive-block-colored servive-block-blue">
                                <h4>Text</h4>
                                <div><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i></div>
                                <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus id elit mi egetine. Fusce dapibus</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="servive-block-in servive-block-colored servive-block-blue">
                                <h4>Why register</h4>
                                <div><i class="icon-globe"></i></div>
                                <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus id elit mi egetine. Fusce dapibus</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/servive-block-->
               </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

CSS:

```
.showcase2 {
position: relative;
z-index: -1;
background: transparent url('../assets/main2.png') center top fixed;
-webkit-background-size: 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100%;
-o-background-size: 100%;
background-size: 100%;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}    

header {
padding: 60px 10px 400px;
text-align: center;
}
.description {
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 60px;
margin: 0;
line-height: 1.25;
color: #20b0ff;
text-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

/* Strip (Call to action) */
.strip {
width: auto;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
background: #232323 url("../assets/texture-1.png");
margin-bottom: 0px;

}
.strip h3 {
color: #FFF;
}
.strip .btn {
margin-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Thanks for you answers!

Comment: your question is not very clear. What are you asking? What are you trying to achieve? What isn't working? Would you mind creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and **being specific** about what the problem is?

Comment: As you can see I have put some textlinks in the showcase, but I can't click on the textlink. I have the same problem with the button Learn more. The button supposed to get blue when I come over with my mouse. When I'm creating an jsfiddle I still have that same problem. I can't click on the links I've created. When I remove the collumns to another part of the code, it works, so I guess the problem is somewhere in the showcase functionality, so I gues the problem is somewhere in my css file. But I can't find out why.

Comment: You need to explain "showcase functionality", what is that?

Comment: I thought I have put the explanation in the CSS file allready. But I found out what the problem was. I think it was the Z-Index in the CSS file. The value was -1. I changed it to 1 and al the links and buttons started working. The showcase is a functionality that different backgrounds lapover when you are scrolling down.

Comment: **please share the jsfiddle with us**. Let us see the problem ourselves. You're describing a bunch of different problems - one that a link doesn't work (which sounds weird, considering it can only be disabled through javascript), one that the button doesn't change to blue on hover (which is css related), and another problem with columns of some mysterious other part of your code. Remember, we don't have the same context as you do, so when we see your code and you mumbling about a bunch of different issues, we have no idea what you need helping with. **Please make it more concise**.